# Why are wave and checker pattern misaligned

Tags: shaders, procedural

I am trying to overlap a wave pattern (for bump/height) and align it with a checkered pattern.
I have divided the wave UV's by PI, which should bring it into phase with the checker texture, but as can be seen in the screenshot, the wave is a bit shorter.

What do I need to do to get the two patterns in sync?

[image]

[image: Example of misalignment]

Comment: Although the modulo helps, it turns out that to align the phases it is wrong to divide by pi. The correct way to align is to divide by (10/pi) which is about 3.18. I needed to base the scaling on the "number of checkers divided by pi".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a modulo so that values are from 0 to 1 before dividing by pi.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This helps with the alignment.